# How to display the total number of the files used in a folder

Tags: c#

This is a part of the code so far:

```
System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}: {2}", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length);
}
System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] dirInfos = dirInfo.GetDirectories("*.*");

foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo d in dirInfos)
{
     Console.WriteLine(d.Name);
}
```

What I want is the output to be like this:  `Total files: 49`

How do I display the `49`?

Comment: what does it mean: `files used in a folder`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use the length of the returned array: `fileNames.Length`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Total files: {0}", fileNames.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fileNames.Length.ToString()
```

will return number of files in the list.